# How to start pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

I have been try to my pipenv going but it gives me this error

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\User\Pipfile
Using C:/Python/Python37/python.exe (3.7.1) to create virtualenv
[  ==] Creating virtual environment...FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
'c:\\python\\python37\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'
Failed creating virtual environment here
```

I tried to changed the file path made sure it is in same path as where python is installed still get the same problem.

Comment: What exactly gave you that error?

Comment: No, what *command* are you running? You don't need to duplicate the *output* of that command in a comment; it's already in the question.

Comment: pipenv install..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy following files from python location(C:\Program Files\Python37) to the (C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\venv\scripts\nt)

```
1) python_d.exe
2) python_d.pdb
3) pythonw_d.exe
4) pythonw_d.pdb
```

Comment: It is a bug when debug binaries are installed. See bugs.python.org/issue36441

Answer (score 0):

thanks this solved the problem just one question if i want to use git clone command which filepath should i used?
because if i used the git clone command in same path

```
C:\Users\User>git clone https://github.com/jadhavpritish/Dream11_Predictor.git  

C:\Users\User>pipenv run python src/player_selection_dream11.py


C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\User-jBUq-HwN\Scripts\python.exe: can't open file 'src/player_selection_dream11.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: use pwd to find complete path of file and use that path

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So what I just did to resolve it is that;

This message popped up (Shortly)

```
[  ==] Creating virtual environment...FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\arham rumi\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'
```

Then I went to the mentioned directory, and there was no such file like `python.exe`
Then I went back to `python37-32` folder or you can simply go to the directory where you have that `python.exe` file. Copy this and paste it to the directory mentioned in the error.
And that's how I resolved this problem